# Ctrl + c not working on continuous ping

Tags: networking, server, keyboard, shortcut-keys

So, I am having this problem with the control key. It seems to happen on occasion.
Currently, I am trying to resolve my wireless connection to my router in Ubuntu Server 16.04.  I sent a command `ping www.google.com` without the `-c 4` option.  It is attempting to ping google and coming back Destination host unreachable over and over and over again.  I am trying to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but all it does is put a C on the screen and try the ping again.

I have tried both control keys and other things like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd>, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>.  Nothing works.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: To end the ping, type on another terminal `killall ping`.  Sorry, I do not have a better answer by now

Answer (score 2):

Try doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Tested on my Kali Linux. I wasn't able to find the reason for it. But it seems like something common and needed so I had to answer even if wasn't able to find the reason.

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + C works on Ubuntu.